# Satellizer Http Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

Currently I'm using satellizer library to authenticate using json web token. On the backend, I have tested the api and the authentication and everything is working. By the way Im using Twitter authentication.

While on the frontend, which the angular part,After I have authenticated with twitter and successfully redirect to home page, I couldn't get user's information whenever i go to **/profile**, it doesnt render the user's information and when I check the network tab on google chrome, angular doesnt even call the /api/me route from the backend.

I believe it has something to do with Http interceptor. The authorization header is set as **x-access-token** both on frontend and backend.

Here's the code.

```
app.js

angular.module('MyApp', [ 'ngMessages','ngRoute', 'ui.router','satellizer'])

  .config(function($authProvider) {

         // Twitter
    $authProvider.authHeader = 'x-access-token';
    $authProvider.httpInterceptor = true; // Add Authorization header to HTTP request
    $authProvider.tokenPrefix = 'twitterAuth'; // Local Storage name prefix


    $authProvider.twitter({
      url: '/auth/twitter',
      type: '1.0',
      popupOptions: { width: 495, height: 645 }
    });


  })



  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html'
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
      })
      .state('logout', {
        url: '/logout',
        template: null,
        controller: 'LogoutCtrl'
      })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


  })
```

the controllers
login.js

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $auth) {

    $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
      $auth.authenticate(provider);
    };

  });
```

profile.js

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $auth, Account) {
    $scope.getProfile = function() {
      Account.getProfile()
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.user = data;
        })
    };
  });
```

services
account.js

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('Account', function($http) {
    return {
      getProfile: function() {
        return $http.get('/api/me');
      }
    };
  });
```

Views
profile.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Profile</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Profile Picture</label>
          <img class="profile-picture" ng-src="{{user.picture || 'http://placehold.it/100x100'}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"><i class="ion-person"></i> Display Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.displayName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"><i class="ion-at"></i> Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" />
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is where the user's information from twitter authentication should render, on the backend everything is showing when I'm using Chrome postman.

I've been pulling my hair for the past 4 hours, so what did I do wrong over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing a call to ProfileCtrl's `$scope.getProfile`. Try this:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, $auth, Account) {
      Account.getProfile()
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.user = data;
        });
  });
```